# How to programmatically add tags to a UIButton in Swift

Tags: swift, swift4

I know how to add tags in `main.storyboard` files, but now I am working on creating everything programmatically. However, I couldn't find anything online that tells me how to add tags to a button. I tried to read the apple documentation but don't know how to implement it.

Here is for example how I created my button, how can I add a tag to it, so that when I make multiple buttons and want to link them to a single action I can know what button has been pressed?

```
let buttonOne() : UIButton { 
   let button = UIButton(type: .system)
   button.backgroundColor = .red
   return button
}()
```

Comment: [UIButton](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton) inherits from [UIView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview) and there is a [tag](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622493-tag) property

Comment: They inherit that the tag 0, I want to change it to for example 2

Comment: Please look at the answer, it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Got it, you’re right it was pretty simple. I thought I did it wrong though, so thought I’d ask :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
let buttonOne() : UIButton { 
   let button = UIButton(type: .system)
   button.backgroundColor = .red
   button.tag = 2
   return button
}()
```

Answer (score 3):

Declare The Button

```
let menuChooseButton = UIButton()
menuChooseButton.frame.origin.y = 0
menuChooseButton.frame.origin.x = xPosition
menuChooseButton.frame.size.width = subViewWidth
menuChooseButton.frame.size.height = subViewHeight
menuChooseButton.backgroundColor = .clear
menuChooseButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
menuChooseButton.tag = i
menuChooseButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(menuSelectAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        menuScrollView.addSubview(menuChooseButton)
```

Define Button Action

```
@objc func menuSelectAction(sender: UIButton!){
    var tagNo: Int = sender.tag
    if tagNo == 0{
        // Whatever you want
    }
}
```